# Google Polymer Repeat value in range 1...n

Tags: repeat, polymer, for-in-loop

I've started messing with Polymer and I've done the basic tutorial with the social media cards. In it several cards care looped over as `repeat="{{post in posts}}"`. What I would like to do is something like `repeat="{{post in range 1...10}}"`. Ultimately I'd like to use a published property cols to provide a max value instead of 10. I've been able to get something like this working by setting the cols property to something like [1,2,...,9] but that is unreasonable to any large set of values. I've also expanded on this by using the `ready` function and executing `this.colsAr = new Array(cols)`, then in the repeat `{{col in colsAr}}.

What is the best/correct method of looping over a variable number of elements where the number is determined by a property?

To add to this lets also say the cols property is dynamically changed via a select input. This should cause a re-draw when a new value is selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the best way to do this is to use a computed property to express your filtered Array.

Something like this:

```
 <template repeat="{{post in slice}}">
   ...
  computed: {
    slice: 'sliced(posts)'
  },
  sliced: function(posts) {
    return posts.slice(1, 3);
  }
```

However, right now, the computed property engine doesn't automatically ArrayObserve `posts`, so we have to manually force a re-compute when the Array structure changes.

```
  kick: 0,
  computed: {
    slice: 'sliced(posts, kick)'
  },
  sliced: function(posts) {
    return posts.slice(1, 3);
  },
  postsChanged: function() {
    this.kick++;
  }
```

Incrementing `kick` forces the data engine to recompute `slice` (gives it a kick). Fwiw, we are trying to improve this particular situation, but the above technique should work in the short term.

Working example:

http://jsbin.com/dadeto/3/edit

Comment: Fwiw, involving another basic variable to affect the behavior of `sliced` is pretty easy, see here: http://jsbin.com/dadeto/4/edit

Comment: That uses an existing array like the posts example in the tutorial. I'm looking to create an array or preferably an inline range like in Python syntax. I've created http://jsbin.com/qudijuxu/3/ as an example of what I'm doing. As a side note it doesn't work in Firefox or Opera because the cols parameter doesn't continue through from the hexgrid to the hexrow.

Comment: It's not clear what 'create an array' vs 'existing array' means. All that matters is that `sliced` (e.g.) has the right inputs so that it can construct whatever you want it to return.

Comment: I believe that Roger doesn't want to loop over an array, he just wants to loop from 1 to N. As far as I know there's no shorthand syntax for doing this in Polymer, but you can use Scott's code above as a starting point for creating a new array whenever `cols` changes.

Comment: Ok, thanks Peter, I understand better now. Yes, for now, you can only repeat over an array.

Comment: Thank you Peter for conveying what I failed to. For now I'll use this method and I'll keep an eye out for some sort of for loop syntax in the future.